# What does the keyword 'for' do?

Tags: html

Looking at the online code samples provided by Bootstrap, you'll see something like this for forms

```
<div class = "control-group">
    <label class = "control-label" for = "name">Full Name</label>
    <div class = "controls">
            <input type = "text" id = "name" maxlength = "40">
    </div>
</div>
```

What does the 'for' word in the label mark up do?  I noticed that if I changed the input id to something that doesn't correspond to the 'for' value, there is no noticeable difference in the output.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO This question was originally under the twitter bootstrap tag, if you search for 'bootstrap for' or 'css for attribute' on Google or SO, you won't find any answers.  Since 'for' is a new attribute and still isn't commonly used outside of bootstrap, I think this is a good place to start.  Your copy and paste comment and down vote really doesn't add any value

Comment: @LloydBanks - `for` is not even close to being a new attribute. It's been standard since [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` is an HTML5 attribute that connect (logically) a label and an input.

[Take a look](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#attr-label-for)

Answer (score 2):

From [the HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#attr-label-for):

> The for attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated.

Note that this is nothing to do with Bootstrap at all. It's a standard `label` element attribute. Its value should correspond to the `id` value of an `input` element:

> If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element in the same Document as the label element.

Comment: Hi James, I don't notice any difference if the for value doesn't match the id of the input element.  Are there any advantages to using for?

Comment: @LloydBanks - It is more semantic to use it as it indicates which field the label is describing. It can also be used by browsers to allow clicks on the label to give focus to the associated input field.

Answer (score 0):

A label can be bound to an element either by using the "for" attribute, or by placing the element inside the  element. [source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)